# Initializing, Configuring & Using Automapper.Collection in an Aspnet core boilerplate project

Tags: automapper, aspnetboilerplate

Can anyone detail how to initialize, configure and use automapper.collection in an aspnet core boilerplate project please. A project sample would be much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure it in the `PreInitialize` method of `YourApplicationModule`.

```cs
Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(
    cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddCollectionMappers();
        cfg.CreateMap<OrderItemDTO, OrderItem>().EqualityComparison((odto, o) => odto.ID == o.ID);
    }
);
```

For EF Core, you have to configure the equivalence for each entity.

For more information, see [AutoMapper.Collection's README.md](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection#readme).